# How do I prepare and send async post request using java-dataloader api

Tags: asynchronous, java-8, http-post, graphql

Currently, I'm using data-loader.2.0.1 as an HTTP-client for one of my GraphQL application's backend call. It works fine for Asynchronous HTTP GET request. But, for the time being, I'm looking for a sample code that does an HTTP POST request asynchronous way with the same library if possible, or any alternative solution if current implementation doesn't support POST call.

For HTTP GET method response, I just did this,

```
dataLoader.load(url);
```